# How to select only unique values from a table column in mysql. NOT using DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, database, select, unique

I'm looking for something other than DISTINCT because with distinct you would return $2.90, $4.78, $1.99. $6.22 with the given column below in a table (let's say table groceries).

```
SELECT DISTINCT price
FROM groceries
```

For example if the whole price column has values:

price:

```
$2.90
$4.78
$1.99
$6.22
$1.99
$2.90
```

I just want the values that are unique only. So the return would be:
    $4.78
    $6.22

How can I do this with not using unique keys and also DISTINCT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT price
FROM groceries
GROUP BY price
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you unique set of `price`:

```
SELECT * FROM  (SELECT COUNT(price) pricecount, price FROM groceries GROUP BY price) a WHERE a.pricecount = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select value from table group by value having count (value)=1

Hope this helps.